# How can I test if the frequencies of alleles and genotypes in two populationes are similar?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, equivalence

I want to test if the frequencies of alleles and genotypes in two different populations can be considered similar. I've read a little, and it seems to be that I should use an equivalence test, but I'm not sure if I really understand it, especially since it seems I have to set some sort of region of similarity, and I don't know how to do that. I was wondering if there's any other way I can test a null hypothesis of difference between the two populations. Or if equivalence tests are the best way to do it, how do I choose the region of similarity, or what is the process to do this type of test.

Comment: Why not simply using a chi-squared ($ \chi^{2} $) test to test whether differences between allele / genotype frequencies exist between populations?

Comment: I already did that, but then I was asked to test whether they are similar, which is something I've been having trouble to do. Equivalence tests are the closest I've come to finding how to do it, but I haven't been able to use them 'cause of the region of similiarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a Bayesian hypothesis test using the software [JASP](https://jasp-stats.org/) which is free. It also does classical analyses, which makes it easy to compare the results. I've attached a few screenshots of how you might do it.

Load the data using a .csv file format.

[image]

Then select "Frequencies" at the top, and then "Contingency tables".

[image]

Then you see a menu like this.

[image]

Move your variable to the appropriate slots. It renders the result in real time.

[image]

So for this classical analysis we see the p-value is not significant, but from that we cannot conclude in favor of an equivalence. This is where the Bayesian test comes in. Go back to the frequencies tab and choose "Bayesian contingency tables".

[image]

Then assign variables as before, and select "BF01" in the "statistics" menu below.

[image]

Now you can see the result of the Bayesian analysis. The Bayes factor in favor of the null model against the alternative is about 7.4. This means that the null model that assumes equivalence is supported over the alternative that assumes a joint multinomial sampling process. Specific details about these Bayesian methods are available [here](http://www.ejwagenmakers.com/submitted/JamilEtAlGunelDickeySubm.pdf). They also work through some examples and give guidance for interpreting the results in context.

Answer (score 0):

You could assume that the allele frequency is some parameter p. Now the sample frequency in a population of size s1 will follow the binomial distribution $P(x1) = {s_1 \choose x_1} p^{x_1}(1-p)^{s_1-x_1}$. The sample frequency in a population of size s2 will follow the binomial distribution  $P(x2) = {s_2 \choose x_2} p^{x_2}(1-p)^{s_2-x_2}$.

Now if you want to be Bayesian, you could find the likelihood ratio assuming a common parameter p vs different parameters $p_1$ and $p_2$.

To get a p-value, you could find $P(x_1/s_1 - x_2/s_2 > y)$ and integrate out $p$. Though this sounds a little weird.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not really sure if I know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

While this fudges a bit with multiple comparisons, perhaps the most useful approach if you have k categories (with two groups) is to get a confidence interval for the difference in proportion, one for each category.  For instance, for this table:

```
> pop1
[1] 13 25 10
> pop2
[1] 33 56 28
> n1 = sum(pop1)
> n2 = sum(pop2)
> prop.test(x=c(13,33),n=c(n1,n2))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity
    correction

data:  c(13, 33) out of c(n1, n2)
X-squared = 0, df = 1, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.1722799  0.1498440
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.2708333 0.2820513 

> prop.test(x=c(25,56),n=c(n1,n2))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity
    correction

data:  c(25, 56) out of c(n1, n2)
X-squared = 0.1031, df = 1, p-value = 0.7482
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.1403170  0.2247187
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.5208333 0.4786325 

> prop.test(x=c(10,28),n=c(n1,n2))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity
    correction

data:  c(10, 28) out of c(n1, n2)
X-squared = 0.051, df = 1, p-value = 0.8214
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.1841523  0.1221865
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.2083333 0.2393162
```

The advantage here is that you get confidence intervals that tell you how different the population proportions of each allele might be, which beats just testing them.  (If I was being careful, I'd change the confidence level using the [Bonferroni correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction)).